# Can I take advantage of the ZIP/XML structure of MS Office files to learn more about them?

Tags: xml, ms-office, openxml

I recently started my first office/desk job, and Excel is the biggest tool I've used so far. Some of my colleagues are way more experienced than me, but since I have some modest programming experience, I was able to contribute by learning VBA and introducing it to my colleagues and incorporating it into our workflow.

While trying to think of ways to further contribute, I remembered reading some time ago that modern MS Office files are actually zip archives in disguise, containing mostly XML files. Unfortunately, after unzipping, I can't do much with it other than finding images and other files that are embedded within the document.

Can I take advantage of this structure to better understand how the files and programs work?

Can editing Open XML be taken one step further and even be considered a viable way to make certain types of changes to a word document or spreadsheet?

Comment: **Close voters:** If you ignore the last sentence, which alone asked further for learning materials, and which I've now removed, the bulk of the question is *not* a request for external resources but a knowledgable beginner's query [worth answering](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70172176/290085).

Comment: _100% anecdotal_: There are some cases where knowing about the internal structure of an Excel file has come in useful - for example, when using [DataTables](https://datatables.net/) and its ability to export data from HTML tables to Excel (`xlsx`). Normally, you do not need to know _anything_ about those internals (thank goodness) - but sometimes you want to customize the exported data in ways which need that extra knowledge. It can get [quite complicated, quite quickly](https://stackoverflow.com/q/67066081/12567365), however. Personally I try very hard to avoid needing to work at that level.

Answer (score 1):

The fact that MS Office files follow standard packaging (Zip) and markup (XML, OpenXML) protocols aids greatly in their accessibility, however the advantage is more toward programatic manipulation than it is toward user learning in a broad sense.

OpenXML is complex and addresses low-level concerns that are better abstracted away from users via an API (or an office application ;-) ).

You're right in that if you understood OOXML thoroughly, you'd understand Office applications at an extraordinary level of detail.  But the same could be said of understanding a compiler and a target architecture for a programming language.  You don't want to start there.  Learn the programming language (Office application) at its own level first.  Progress next to using an API for programmatic access.  Finally, if necessary, learn XML in general and OOXML in specific for the ultimate in understanding and control.